# SELECT SQL query that will return the latest values based on time, grouped into a single row

Tags: sql, database, amazon-athena

Is it possible to write a SELECT SQL query that will return the latest values based on time, grouped into a single row?

```
time| id  |  a  |  b  | c  | d
----+-----+-----+-----+----+----
 1  |  1  |  a1 |     |    |
 2  |  1  |     |  b1 |    |
 3  |  1  |     |     | c0 |
 4  |  1  |  a3 |     | c3 |
 5  |  1  |  a0 |     |    |
```

The result should look like this:

```
id  |  a  |  b  | c  | d
----+-----+-----+----+----
 1  |  a0 |  b1 | c3 |
```

The database used is AWS Athena.

Comment: Please add tags of your database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,
  FIRST_VALUE(a) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, time DESC) a,
  FIRST_VALUE(b) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY CASE WHEN b IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, time DESC) b,
  FIRST_VALUE(c) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, time DESC) c,
  FIRST_VALUE(d) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY CASE WHEN d IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, time DESC) d
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2d29838d00aa852c302c1548189c82ed) (for MySql but it is standard SQL).
Results:

```
> id | a  | b  | c  |    d
> -: | :- | :- | :- | ---:
>  1 | a0 | b1 | c3 | null
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is with a CTE data for an illustration (sorry, I saw your edit after answering. I am not familiar with AWS Athena, using Postgresql syntax flavour). Works for more than one `id`.

```sql
with t("time", id, a, b, c, d) as 
(
 values
 (1, 1, 'a1', null, null, null),
 (2, 1, null, 'b1', null, null),
 (3, 1, null, null, 'c0', null),
 (4, 1, 'a3', null, 'c1', null),
 (5, 1, 'a0', null, null, null),
 (1, 2, 'a1', null, null, null),
 (2, 2, null, 'b1', null, null),
 (3, 2, null, null, 'c0', null),
 (4, 2, 'a3', 'b2', 'c1', 'd3'),
 (5, 2, null, null, 'c3', null)
),
u(id, name) as 
(
 values 
 (1, 'john'), 
 (2, 'paul'), 
 (3, 'mark') 
)
select ext.id, max(u.name) "name",
 (select a from t where a is not null and id = ext.id order by "time" desc limit 1),
 (select b from t where b is not null and id = ext.id order by "time" desc limit 1),
 (select c from t where c is not null and id = ext.id order by "time" desc limit 1),
 (select d from t where d is not null and id = ext.id order by "time" desc limit 1)
from t ext join u on ext.id = u.id group by ext.id;
```

Result:

```
id|name|a |b |c |d |
--|----|--|--|--|--|
 1|john|a0|b1|c1|  |
 2|paul|a3|b2|c3|d3|
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a follow-up question How would you go about incorporating your sql statement above with another table (users) that you wanted to left join with table t on id?  Say that table users is defined like this:  with users(id, name) as 
(
values
(1, 'john'),
(2, 'paul'),
(3, 'mark')
)

Comment: @WawrzyniecPruski I have editted the answer to incorporate users table.

Comment: Does you know how to get the above working with same tables set up in AWS Athena DB?  I get the following error:  Your query has the following error(s):

Unsupported correlated subquery type

Comment: @WawrzyniecPruski Sorry, no, I am not familiar with AWS Athena DB.